# WCF is not working properly in VS2012

Tags: wcf, iis, visual-studio-2012

I installed VS2012 and now I'm trying to add a new WCF service to a project in my localhost but all I see when I browse the svc file is the default GetData. I cant see my own OperationContract or messages. It is not updating even in the visual studio discovery when I want to add it as a service reference.

Anybody knows the fix?

Just realized that if I add a new WCF app and change them it is working. But when I host it in IIS I can update it. So the problem is with IIS and VS2012.